# Rust &String to &str implicit conversion

Tags: string, rust, slice, implicit-conversion

Let's consider this code for my question
The playground link can be found here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=400f59f484d86826de5829ba3f29fc89

```rust
fn print_a(a: &str) {
    println!("this is a: {}", a);
}

struct MyA {
    a: String,
}

impl From<&str> for MyA {
    fn from(a: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            a: format!("This is a: {}", a),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = "Hello, World!".to_string();
    print_a(&a);
    let b = MyA::from(&a);
    println!("b.a: {}", b.a);
}
```

I know I could use something like `let b = MyA::from(a.as_str());`, but why `let b = MyA::from(&a);` does not work but `print_a(&a)` work?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/5397009

Comment: `print_a (&a)` works because `String` implements `Deref<Target=str>`. `MyA::from (&a)` doesn't work because `from` is not directly a method from `MyA`, and the compiler doesn't consider `Deref` when looking for traits that may contain the method.

Comment: This works by the way `let b = <MyA as From<&str>>::from(&a);`.

Comment: @Rodolfo that's because this unambiguously specifies the instance of `From` being expected, therefore the function call is completely defined (as with `print_a`).

Comment: `let b: MyA = From::<&str>::(&a)` also works, because the pair of output type and parameterized trait also unambiguously specify which implementation of `From` (and thus which version of `From::from`) is expected.